# How to do different types of bootstrap in r?

Tags: statistics-bootstrap

My bootstrap code in R gives an error and I can't see what is wrong with it. Does somebody see it?

```
B <- 10000
bootstrap.results <- matrix(nrow=B,ncol=3)
colnames(bootstrap.results) <- c("mu","sigma","convergence")
for (b in 1:B){
sample.b <- rnorm(n,mean=1,sd=1.5)
m.b <- optim(c(mu=0,sd=1),loglik,control=list(fnscale=-1),z=sample.b)
bootstrap.results[b,] <- c(m.b$par,m.b$convergence)
}
```

Does anybody have a general code for bootstrap (parametric/nonparametric) that they always use?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following code where I generate B = 10000 samples of n = 30 observations from a normal distribution with µ = 1 and σ 2 = 2.25. For each sample, the parameters µ and σ are estimated and stored in a matrix. I hope this can help you.

```
B <- 10000
bootstrap.results <- matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=3)
colnames(bootstrap.results) <- c("mu","sigma","convergence")
for (b in 1:B){
  sample.b <- rnorm(n,mean=1,sd=1.5)
  m.b <- optim(c(mu=0,sd=1),loglik,control=list(fnscale=-1),z=sample.b)
  bootstrap.results[b,] <- c(m.b$par,m.b$convergence)
}

loglik <- function(p,z){
  sum(dnorm(z,mean=p[1],sd=p[2],log=TRUE))
}
set.seed(45)
n <- 30
x <- rnorm(n,mean=1,sd=1.5)
optim(c(mu=0,sd=1),loglik,control=list(fnscale=-1),z=x)
```

One can also obtain the ML estimate of λ and use the bootstrap to estimate the bias and the standard error of the estimate. First calculate the MLE of λ Then, we estimate the bias and the standard error of λˆ by a nonparametric bootstrap.

```
B <- 9999
lambda.B <- rep(NA,B)
n <- length(w.time)
for (b in 1:B){
  b.sample <- sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE)
  lambda.B[b] <- 1/mean(w.time[b.sample])
}
bias <- mean(lambda.B-m$estimate)
sd(lambda.B)
In the second part we calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean time between failures.

n <- length(w.time)
m <- mean(w.time)
se <- sd(w.time)/sqrt(n)
interval.1 <- m + se * qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))
interval.1
```

But we can also use the the assumption that the data are from an exponential distribution. In that case we have varX¯ = 1/(nλ^2) = θ^{2}/n which can be estimated by X¯^{2}/n.

```
sd.m <- sqrt(m^2/n)
interval.2 <- m + sd.m * qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))
interval.2
We can also estimate the standard error of ˆθ by means of a boostrap procedure. We use the nonparametric bootstrap, that is, we sample from the original sample with replacement.

B <- 9999
m.star <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  m.star[b] <- mean(sample(w.time,replace=TRUE))
}
sd.m.star <- sd(m.star)
interval.3 <- m + sd.m.star * qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))
interval.3
An interval not based on the assumption of normality of ˆθ is obtained by the percentile method:

  interval.4 <- quantile(m.star, probs=c(0.025,0.975))
interval.4
```

--

For the bootstrap to work, it is important that the observations are independently, 
identically distributed, and that the distribution of your estimates converges to 
the corresponding population distribution. In the example below I estimate a regression model
with 20 observations. Suppose now that for some reason every observation is entered twice.
In that case, I would need to bootstrap over the original observations, 
to get appropriate standard errors.

```
set.seed(45)
x <- 2*rnorm(20)
epsilon <- rnorm(20)
y <- 1 - 0.5*x + epsilon # y variable is the regression
data1 <- data.frame(y=y,x=x,obs.id=1:20)
summary(lm(y~x,data=data1))
now the dataset is entered twice but we know the id's of the original observations

data2 <- rbind(data1,data1)
summary(lm(y~x,data=data2))
```

the coefficients are exactly the same, but the estimated standard errors are wrong 
due to the duplication of the dataset. The data are depenndent, 
the independent units of observation are the id's

```
B <- 10000
boot.b <- matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=2)
all.ids <- cbind(1:20,line1=1:20,line2=21:40)
for (b in 1:B){
  ids.b <- sample(all.ids[,1],20,replace=TRUE)
  lines.b <- c(all.ids[ids.b,2],all.ids[ids.b,3])
  data.b <- data2[lines.b,]
  boot.b[b,] <- coef(lm(y~x,data=data.b))
}
colMeans(boot.b)

coef(lm(y~x,data=data1))

var(boot.b)

vcov(lm(y~x,data=data1))

vcov(lm(y~x,data=data2))
```

The bootstrap standard errors are close to the ones of the correct dataset,
because the bootstrap as specified in the for-loop takes the dependence between
observations into account.

--

normal 99% loss quantile with confidence band
delta method

```
quantile(aex$d.return.aex,probs=0.99)

library(MASS)
m.n <- fitdistr(aex$d.return.aex,"normal")
m.n$estimate
m.n$vcov
q.hat <- m.n$estimate[1]+m.n$estimate[2]*qnorm(0.99)
q.hat
var.q.hat <- t(c(1,qnorm(0.99))) %*% m.n$vcov %*% c(1,qnorm(0.99))
sqrt(var.q.hat)
normal.interval <-q.hat + sqrt(c(var.q.hat))*qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))
normal.interval
```

parametric bootstrap 1

```
B <- 9999
n.obs <- nrow(aex)
q.star1 <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  sample.b <- rnorm(n.obs,mean=m.n$estimate[1],sd=m.n$estimate[2])
  m.b <- fitdistr(sample.b,"normal")
  q.star1[b] <- m.b$estimate[1]+m.b$estimate[2]*qnorm(0.99)
}
q1 <- quantile(q.star1,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
q1
```

parametric bootstrap 2

```
q.star2 <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  theta.b <- mvrnorm(1,mu=m.n$estimate,Sigma=m.n$vcov)
  q.star2[b] <- theta.b[1]+theta.b[2]*qnorm(0.99)
}
q2 <- quantile(q.star2,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
q2
```

t distribution

```
m.t <- fitdistr(aex$d.return.aex,"t")
m.t$estimate
m.t$vcov
q.hat <- m.t$estimate[1]+m.t$estimate[2]*qt(0.99,m.t$estimate[3])
q.hat
```

delta method ....

```
library(numDeriv)
```

parametric bootstrap 3

```
B <- 99
q.star3 <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  sample.b <- m.t$estimate[1]+m.t$estimate[2]*rt(n.obs,df=m.t$estimate[3])
  m.b <- fitdistr(sample.b,"t")
  q.star3[b] <- m.b$estimate[1]+m.b$estimate[2]*qt(0.99,m.b$estimate[3])
}
q3 <- quantile(q.star3,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
q3
```

parametric bootstrap 4

```
B <- 9999
q.star4 <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  theta.b <- mvrnorm(1,mu=m.t$estimate,Sigma=m.t$vcov)
  q.star4[b] <- theta.b[1]+theta.b[2]*qt(0.99,theta.b[3])
}
q4 <- quantile(q.star4,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
q4
```

non parametric bootstrap with percentile method

```
B <- 99
q.star5 <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B){
  sample.b <- sample(aex$d.return.aex,size=n.obs,replace=TRUE)
  m.b <- fitdistr(sample.b,"t")
  q.star5[b] <- quantile(sample.b,probs=0.99)
}
q5 <- quantile(q.star5,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
q5

rbind(delta=normal.interval,normal.par.1=q1,normal.par.2=q2,
      delta.t=normal.interval.t,
      t.par.1=q3,
      t.par.2=q4,non.par=q5)
```